# Numberless sectionmark

Tags: sectioning, fancyhdr, titlesec

#### Context

I am trying to display the name of a numberless section (`\section*{}`) in the header of a document with the `fancyhdr` package.

I am already displaying the name of sections and removing their numbering from the label with the `extramark` and `titlesec` packages.

#### Issue

The numberless section does not appear in the header leaving it empty. It seems to work properly for the table of contents which is also a numberless section (correct me if I am wrong).

#### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mwe}

\usepackage{extramarks}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\title{Document}

\fancyhead[L]{}
\fancyhead[R]{
  {\nouppercase
  \firstleftmark}
}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}

\begin{document}

\section*{Test}
\newpage
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\blinddocument

\end{document}
```

#### Example

[image: Numberless section empty header]
[image: Contents displaying properly]
[image: Classic section]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can manually trigger the entry in the headline for the unnumbered section:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mwe}

\usepackage{extramarks}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\title{Document}

\fancyhead[L]{}
\fancyhead[R]{
  {\nouppercase
  \firstleftmark}
}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}

\begin{document}

\section*{Test}
\markboth{Test}{}

\newpage
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\blinddocument

\end{document}
```

Comment: While this does indeed fix this specific issue, it does require to type twice the name of the section. Is it possible to automatically retrieve it somehow?

Comment: @Florian Something like `\renewcommand*{\secwhead}[1]{\section*{#1}\sectionmark{#1}}`? (Could be improved for optional arguments etc. etc.)